# Почтовый клиент Java

Tags: сокет, клиент, java

Почему программа не завершает работу, а остаётся зависшей?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NewMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static String tmpStr;
    static StringBuffer tmpBuff = new StringBuffer();
    public static String string;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Socket s = new Socket("pop.yandex.ru", 110);
        s.getOutputStream().write("USER thisisforjava".getBytes("iso-8859-1"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"));

        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (!line.startsWith("+OK")) break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас падает исключению, но его никто не ловит. Оно идет на уровень выше. Правильно было бы:

1. Отлавливать исключения IOException
2. Закрывать reader и socket в finally блоке.
3. Изменить логику работы с reader.

Так, у объекта типа reader есть метод ready, сообщающий о готовности. Сразу после направления одного потока в другой reader будет пуст, ready = false. Мы должны сначала дождаться, когда наступит готовность, и только тогда приступать к чтению из буфера с помощью метода readLine. В противном случае будет брошено исключение, которое в вашем примере и происxодило.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NewMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket s = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket("pop.yandex.ru", 110);
        s.getOutputStream().write("USER thisisforjava".getBytes("iso-8859-1"));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
        while (true) {
            if (!br.ready()) continue; 
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("+OK")) {
                System.out.println(line);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А почему в ответ на мои запросы всегда приходит +ОК, даже когда я неправильно ввожу пароль? Как узнать, что я успешно залогинился?

Comment: Так поинтересуйтесь протоколом POP3. Он говорит +OK при подключении и в ответ на USER. Если после этого сказать PASS с неправильным паролем, то в ответ скажут, что -ERR [AUTH] login failure, try later.